# Trouble with React Native Push Notification

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm currently working on a Android mobile App.

It's a kitchen recipes app. The app will send notification to the user during the day.

In the settings of the app, the user can choose how many and at what time he will receive the notifications (11 am to 7 pm for example)

This is where the problem begins;

I use the [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) library with the following code:

```
static LocalNotif(string)
{
    PushNotification.localNotification({
        vibrate: true, // (optional) default: true
        vibration: 300, // vibration length in milliseconds, ignored if vibrate=false, default: 1000
        title: "Vérifier vos produit", // (optional)
        message: string, // (required)
        largeIcon: "ic_launcher",
        smallIcon: "ic_notification",
        });    
}
```

Next, I use the [react-native-background-fetch](https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-fetch) to send a notification, even if the app is not running

```
static async backFetch(delay_to_next_notif)
{
    BackgroundFetch.configure({
        minimumFetchInterval: 3600
      }, async (taskId) => {
        // This is the fetch-event callback.
        console.log("[BackgroundFetch] taskId: ", taskId);
      
        // Use a switch statement to route task-handling.
        switch (taskId) {
          case 'com.foo.customtask':
            this.LocalNotif("test")
            break;
          default:
            console.log("Default fetch task");
        }
        // Finish, providing received taskId.
        BackgroundFetch.finish(taskId);
      });
      
      // Step 2:  Schedule a custom "oneshot" task "com.foo.customtask" to execute 5000ms from now.
      BackgroundFetch.scheduleTask({
        taskId: "com.foo.customtask",
        forceAlarmManager: true,
        delay: delay_to_next_notif// <-- milliseconds
      });
}
```

The use of [react-native-background-fetch](https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-fetch) is very strange. Sometime I never receive the notification.

Is it possible to use a push notification library and create a routine so that the user receives notifications at specific times during the day, even if the app is not running?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pushnptification.configure method and set your state if your app is in forground or background something like this

```
async componentDidMount() {
        await this.requestUserPermission();
        PushNotification.configure({
          onNotification: (notification) => {
            console.log('NOTIFICATION', notification);
            if (notification.foreground === false) {
              console.log('app is in background')
            }
    
            this.setState({
              msg: notification.message.body
                ? notification.message.body
                : notification.message,
    
              forground: notification.foreground,
            });
          },
        });
      }
```

and in your return u can do something like this

```
{this.state.forground === true
            ? showMessage({
                message: this.state.msg,

                backgroundColor: '#1191cf',
                type: 'default',
                duration: 10000,
                icon: 'success',

                onPress: () => {
                  console.log('app is in forground')
                },
              })
        : null}
```